# COM exception when using ServerManager class from Microsoft.Web.Administration

Tags: .net, iis

I'm trying to retrieve a website from IIS with following code:

```
var serverManager = new ServerManager();

var site = serverManager.Sites.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == Config.WebSiteName);
```

`ServerManager` class is defined in `Microsoft.Web.Administration`, I'm using reference with copy local and the dll is deployed with the application.

If my app is ran on Win7 64bit it works correctly but when I try to run it on Windows XP 32 it throws an exception:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {2B72133B-3F5B-4602-8952-803546CE3344} failed due to the following error: 80040154

I'm deploying the app as stand alone winforms .net 3.5 application (built for Any CPU).

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That error is `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG`, i.e. the code it's trying to call doesn't exist on your XP machine. From [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager.aspx)

> Provides read and write access to the IIS 7 configuration system.

Win XP Pro only has IIS 6 not 7. You'll have to use some other mechanism, e.g. [iisweb.vbs](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/69a90de9-1492-45b2-853e-1e7457f309db.mspx?mfr=true), adplus or the COM objects they use behind the scenes.

Comment: How did you know that '80040154' meant 'REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG'?

Comment: @BSick7 There's a utility err.exe that maps codes to constants. You can find the latest version in the Windows SDK. I think it's also possible using Visual Studio (certainly VS6 bundled an app that did it) but I'm not sure how. And with a bit of effort you can also dig it out of the header files, although many constants like this are assembled from parts so it can take some effort.